# How to remove span with class name around selected text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to highlight selected text and remove selected text when the user wants. 
I have almost done everything, but I am stuck when it comes to remove the style of the selected text. 
I want to remove span with class name `highlight` around selected text but not remove other styles which are already available inside selected text.

Here is [the plunk I've made](https://plnkr.co/edit/qBEbHqK77aLYVPYrMKlp?p=preview):

```
function removeHighlight() {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedTextNode = document.createTextNode(range.toString());
    console.log(selectedTextNode);
    range.deleteContents();
    range.insertNode(selectedTextNode);
    range.selectNode(selectedTextNode);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}
```

What is the proper way to remove highlighted span around selected text ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `remove` method of the `classList` property:

```
// Get all the spans that have the highlight class
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span.highlight");

// Loop over the spans and remove the classs
for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
  spans[i].classList.remove("highlight");
}
```

Comment: i dont't want to remove only class name, i want to remove span tag around text

Comment: Can I ask why you have that particular requirement?

Comment: and at one time i have to remove only one highlight. above your method remove all span's style. and here i can't get which highlight user want to remove. i have only range object here

Comment: @GiteshPurbia My method only removes the `highlight` class from the `span` elements. Any other styles remain intact.

Comment: i have a range object, and i have a problem in getting span with class name highlight. you can see the demo whats the problem exactly i am facing

Comment: @GiteshPurbia I think what you need to do is rethink the solution. Instead of removing the highlight, you should just create a more specific style that overrides the highlight when a user selects some text.

Comment: login and open one book here and highlight text here and remove it again. and see to dom's with inspect. that is exact i want to do here  is the link. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/handbook-of-research/9781522522294/978-1-5225-2229-4.chcrf.xhtml